# Tensorflow Object Detection API on Windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, object-detection

Tensorflow recently released their new [object detection api](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection) Is there any way to run this on windows? The directions apear to be for linux.

Comment: Its just this jupyter notebook: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb. If you have `python/anaconda` and `tensorflow`, you should be able to run it.

Comment: if you use Docker, you can run on any platform.
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/
I'd recommend you deploy tensorflow with docker, much easier than installing yourself.
https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/

obviously you can install natively too. Anaconda as mentioned, is a good tool for Windows, but i don't know how well it does with TensorFlow.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can run the Tensorflow Object Detection API on Windows. Unfortunately it is a bit tricky and the official documentation does not reflect that appropriately. I used the following procedure:

- Install Tensorflow [natively on Windows with Anaconda + CUDA + cuDNN](https://github.com/philferriere/dlwin). Note that TF 1.5 is now built against CUDA 9.0, so make sure you download the appropriate versions.
- Then you clone the repository and build the Protobuf files as described in the tutorial, but beware, there is a bug in [Windows Protobuf 3.5](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/3957), so make sure you use [version 3.4](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.4.0/).

  ```
  cd [TF-models]\research
  protoc.exe object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
  ```
- Finally, you need to build and install the packages with

  ```
  cd [TF-models]\research\slim
  python setup.py install
  cd [TF-models]\research
  python setup.py install
  ```

  If you get the exception *error: could not create 'BUILD': Cannot create a file when that file already exists here*, delete the BUILD file inside first, it will be re-created automatically
- And make the built binaries [available to your path python path](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#add-libraries-to-pythonpath), or simply copy the directories `slim` and `object_detection` to your `[Anaconda3]/Lib/site-packages` directory

To see everything put together, check out our [Music Object Detector](https://github.com/apacha/MusicObjectDetector-TF/tree/master/MusicObjectDetector), which was trained on Windows and Linux.

Comment: i couldn't find `setup.py` in the slim directory with the latest tensorflow, i can only find it in the `slim` directory

Answer (score 1):

We don't officially support the Tensorflow Object Detection API, but some external users have gotten it to work.

Our dependencies are pillow, lxml, jupyter, matplotlib and protobuf compiler. You can download a version of the protobuf compiler [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases). The remaining dependencies can be installed with pip.

Answer (score 0):

As I said on the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46394718/5330223), you can use your local GPU in windows, as Tensorflow supports GPU on python.

And [here](https://github.com/sumsuddin/Tensorflow-Windows-Person-Detection) is an example.

Unfortunately, Tensoflow does not support `tensorflow-serving` on windows. Also as you said `Nvidia-Docker` is not supported on windows. `Bash on windows` has no support for GPU either. So I think this is the only easy way to go for now.

Answer (score 0):

The below tutorial was build specifically for using the Tensorflow Object Detection API on Windows.  I've successfully used the below tutorial many times:

https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10