# Tensorflow Object Detection API with GPU on Windows and real-time detection

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, real-time, video-processing

I am testing the new **Tensorflow Object Detection API** in Python, and I succeeded in installing it on Windows using docker. However, my trained model (Faster RCNN resnet101 COCO) **takes up to 15 seconds to make a prediction** (with very good accuracy though), probably because I only use Tensorflow CPU.

My three questions are:

- Considering the latency, where is the problem? I heard Faster RCNN was a good model for low latency visual detection, is it because of the CPU-only execution?
- With such latency, is it possible to make efficient realtime video processing by using tensorflow GPU, or should I use a more popular model like YOLO?
- The popular mean to use tensorflow GPU in docker is nvidia-docker but is not supported on windows. Should I continue to look for a docker (or conda) solution for local prediction, or should I deploy my model directly to a virtual instance with GPU (I am comfortable with Google Cloud Platform)?

Any advice and/or good practice concerning real-time video processing with Tensorflow is very welcome!

Comment: Is the 15 seconds including Session/graph creation time? That may add a few seconds, which could be cached away in the steady state (i.e. keep one or more sessions around with your graph loaded). SIMD (AVX, AVX2, etc.) would also be important for serving image models on the CPU, and enabling MKL may be helpful too.

Comment: The 15seconds does not include Session/graph time, it's the time of a sess.run(), that's why I'm very surprised. I will try with SIMD et MKL enabled, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

> Considering the latency, where is the problem ? I heard Faster RCNN
>   was a good model for low latency visual detection, is it because of
>   the CPU-only execution ?

Of course, it's because you are using CPU.

> With such latency, is it possible to make efficient realtime video
>   processing by using tensorflow GPU, or should I use a more popular
>   model like YOLO ?

Yolo is fast, but I once used it for face and accuracy was not that great. But a good alternative.

> The popular mean to use tensorflow GPU in docker is nvidia-docker but
>   is not supported on windows. Should I continue to look for a docker
>   (or conda) solution for local prediction, or should I deploy my model
>   directly to a virtual instance with GPU (I am comfortable with Google
>   Cloud Platform) ?

I think you can still use your local GPU in windows, as Tensorflow supports GPU on python.

And [here](https://github.com/sumsuddin/Tensorflow-Windows-Person-Detection) is an example, simply to do that. It has a client which can read webcam or IP cam stream. The server is using Tensorflow python GPU version and ready to use pre-trained model for predictions.

Unfortunately, Tensoflow does not support `tensorflow-serving` on windows. Also as you said `Nvidia-Docker` is not supported on windows. `Bash on windows` has no support for GPU either. So I think this is the only easy way to go for now.